# Is there a way to automatically run a script after grub-install?

Tags: grub2

I would like to automatically run a script after `grub-install` (using Grub2) if it's  possible?

Some context. The script will simply run `grub-install /dev/sda1`, `grub-install /dev/sdb1`, `grub-install /dev/sdc1` as I want all three EFI boot partitions in sync.

Comment: grub-install is a shell script, just edit it

Comment: @warl0ck: I think it will get removed when an update of `grub-install` occurs. Which might very well be just when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put `grub-install` along with these three commands in a file and add it somewhere in the PATH so that you can run it whenever you need to.

Alternatively alias `grub-install` in root's `~/.bashrc` (depending on what shell root uses) to `grub-install && grub-install /dev/sd{a,b,c}1`

Comment: My main concern is when doing `apt-get dist-upgrade`, I want all three HDD's to get updated then. I don't think `.bashrc` is read when running commands through `sudo`. Creating a script and putting it somewhere on roots path also doesn't help, as it's not only when I run it I want to make sure all three HDD's are addressed.